# What is wrong in the stack implementation using linked lists?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement a stack using linked list. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
//implementation of stack
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};
struct Stack{
    struct Node* headNode;
    struct Node* presentNode;
    int size;
};
struct Node* newNode()
{
    struct Node* node;
    return node;
}
struct Stack* newStack()
{
    struct Stack* stack;
    stack->headNode = newNode();
    stack->presentNode = stack->headNode;
    stack->size=0;
    return stack;
}

int isempty(struct Stack* s)
{
    if(s->headNode->next != NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

void push(struct Stack* s,int data)
{
    struct Node* node = newNode();
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    s->presentNode->next = node;
    node->prev = s->presentNode;
    s->presentNode = node;
    s->size ++;
}

int pop(struct Stack*s)
{
    if(isempty(s)==1)
        return 0;
    int data = s->presentNode->data;
    s->presentNode->prev->next = NULL;
    s->presentNode = s->presentNode->prev;
    s->size --;
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    struct Stack* stack = newStack();
    int data = 0,type;
    printf("Enter '1' if new element to be added or '0' if the latest element is to be deleted.\n");
    while(data!=-1)//unbounded stack
    //takes input until data==-1
    {
        scanf("%d",&type);
        if(type)
        {
            printf("Enter the element:\t");
            scanf("%d",&data);
            if(data==-1)
                continue;
            push(stack,data);
        }
        else
            printf("%d is popped out of the list!\n",pop(stack));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting `run-time error`. Since I am new to pointers (I am a Java guy), I am pretty confused where my error is, although I am sure it is due to pointers.

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for your stack (calls to malloc). At this point all you've got is a big bowl of undefined behavior as your pointers point to nothing.

Comment: You are not allocating memory while creating a new node.
See your `struct Node* newNode()` function. you are missing `malloc()`.

Comment: Put Java aside. Learn C as though you don't know a thing about programming. Other than being curly braces programming languages, the two have virtually nothing in common. You will only shoot yourself in the foot if you rely on your Java intuition too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not allocate memory for your new nodes:

```
struct Node* newNode()
{
  struct Node* node;
  return node;
}
```

Local variable `node` is an uninitialized pointer. As soon as you use the return value of this function, you have Undefined Behaviour.

Edit:
The same problem is true for `newStack`:

```
struct Stack* newStack()
{
    struct Stack* stack;
    stack->headNode = newNode();
...
    return stack;
}
```

As soon as you dereference `stack`, you have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: what should be the size of memory allocation if I want an unbound stack?

Comment: As you only store an `int` inside your nodes, `sizeof(struct Node)` might be a good starting point.

Comment: Something more precise than "I get an error" would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems. For starters

- In your `newStack()` function, you do not have a `return` statement, so using the return value causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- You need to allocate memory to pointers (i.e., make pointers to point to valid memory) before you can actually dereference them. In your case

  ```
  struct Stack* stack;
  stack->headNode
  ```

  is an attempt to use uninitialized memory which again causes UB.

Comment: It was a error while copying the code....ignore it....I have edited the question.